# AttributeError in Python function: object has no attribute

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpZPe.jpg)Good day to everyone!

Can someone please help me?

What is wrong in my python code?

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @classmethod
    def zero(cls):
        return cls(0, 0)

    def draw(self):
        print(f"Point ({self.x}, {self.y}")


point = Point.zero
point.draw()
```

Ouput:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'draw'
```

Comment: Look at the last line of code in that image you posted and find the differences...

Answer (score 1):

You didn't call the class method. `point` is just another reference to it.

```
point = Point.zero()
```